# DRYing up references in a step file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I’m using RSpec and Turnip for acceptance tests.  My steps file has a hash that is used and modified in several different private methods.  I’d like to DRY things up, but since the hash is modified for some steps, I can’t just create a constant.

Inside one private method I do something like:

```
def my_private_method
     { score1: 13, score2: 24, score3: 12}.each do |element, score|
     #do stuff
     ...
     }
end
```

and in another,

```
def second_private_method
    my_hash = { score1: 13, score2: 24, score3: 12}
     ...
    my_hash[:score1] = nil
     ...
end
```

I have tried creating the hash like this:

```
@my_hash =
  {
    score1: 1.2,
    score2: 8.7,
    score3: 6.4
  }
```

and then referring to it as @my_hash in the private methods, but it is always nil. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you defining this hash instance var?

Comment: I have tried defining it at the top of the file before any steps, and also under the private label.  Neither works, I still get a nil reference.